# full featured jquery form submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please supply a full example of a jquery form submit button where:

- the button changes appearance when pushed down, and also shows "please wait" for the correct time.
- it's safe for use on forms
- if possible, it will still work if someone has javascript disabled (I realize this may not be possible, but would be a nice to have).

Thanks much

Comment: There are various posts on different parts of this, just not one that puts it altogether.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?  The reason there is no tutorial on all these things in one place is that these are very broad spectrum issues.  Changing the button appearance is both js and css. Security of the form submission is boh an issue in js and on your server.

Comment: I plan to change the button appearance by using CSS3PIE / CSS3, to get nice appearance -- i.e. just via setting a style either on the link or on a div surrounding the link.  I had problems with doing a button before and am just looking for someone that has a decent example working that they are willing to "donate".  Thanks

Comment: Also ideally noting any issues / trade-offs if it can't meet all the goals.

Comment: How can you have a jQuery (i.e. JavaScript) button that works even when JavaScript is disabled? Are you looking for graceful degradation back to a standard form submit button?

Comment: This sounds like a project manager trying to do a developer's job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery will do just fine.

First you build a normal form, give the `<form>` tag an id, say `#someform`, and an id to the submit button, say `#somebutton`.

Then you bind an handler to `#someform`:

```
$('#someform').submit(function(){
    var params=$(this).serialize();
    //here you submit params using $.post
    document.selectElementById('somebutton').disabled=true;
    return false;
})
```

It will work with or without js support.

Comment: Thanks Rufus, this is helpful.  Am still working with your answer and other stuff I'm looking at.